# why is it called an eigenvalue in this situation

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In my book they study the following problem :

> Let $r \in C^{\infty}([0,1])$, and let $\lambda$ be a real number, then we consider the following DE : 
>   $$y'' + (\lambda -r) y = 0$$
>
> We denote $L_{\lambda}$ the vector space of solutions statifying $y(0) = y(1) = 0$, and if $L_{\lambda} \ne 0$ we say that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.

I am wondering why they call it an eigenvalue ? I mean for me an eigenvalue is when you have a matrix $A$ and a $\lambda$ such that : $Av = \lambda v$ for some $v \ne 0$. Yet here where is the matrix ?

Thank you !

Comment: You can refer to an eigrnvalue of *any* linear transformation.  It just so happens that matrices are used to represent several early examples of linear transformations between finite dimensional vector spaces.  Differentiation is also a linear transformation and so too deserves the same terminology.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ok but then here where is the linear transformation $T$ such that we have $Tv = \lambda v$ ?

Comment: I expect you have a typo and should have instead $y(0)=y(1)=0$ rather than $1$.  Rearrange things to $\lambda y = ry- y''$.  Your linear transformation being discussed here is $T(y) = ry-y''$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, an Eigenelement is an element such that a given transformation turns it to a multiple of itself, and the corresponding proportionality coefficient is an Eigenvalue.

In the case of a matrix applied to a vector,

$$Ax=\lambda x$$ associates an Eigenvector and an Eigenvalue. The transformation is described by a matrix.

In the case of your linear ODE,

$$\left(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+r\right)y=\lambda y$$ associates an Eigenfunction and an Eigenvalue. The transformation is described by a differential operator.